# Building old-style ASP.net application (with System.Web)

Tags: asp.net

I have an old asp.net that I'd like to move from a Windows environment to Linux.

The application has an old Web.config, a bunch of dlls and an App_code folder.

Can you point me in the right direction to getting this working?

What I've tried so far:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -o /var/www/blah
```

But this complains:

```
app_code/Rewriter.cs(3,14): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Web' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?
```

I read that System.Web doesn't really exist anymore.

My question is, can I reference some kind of build environment that will build and deploy this old-style application? Or so I need to port all the code?

Comment: You won’t be able to migrate a Webforms site to ASP.NET Core

Comment: I was actually able to migrate to linux using mono.net.

Answer (score 1):

Migrate any business logic to classes, so you can reuse it. The more code you can move to classes (or even class libraries), the easier it will be. Then create a new ASP.NET core application and rebuild the UI bits.

The hardest part is if you have a lot of spaghetti because you over-utilized the event methods in your code behind files. You may end up with a lot of refactoring, but the idea is to keep it working as is, but with the actual code outside of the ASPX pages. Once your event handlers look more like this

```
public void THisButton_Click(e as EventArgs)
{
    OtherClass.Method();
}
```

you will find it much easier to migrate to MVC, which is how you will want to design the UI with for ASP.NET Core.

If this is not making sense, let me know, and I can see if I can point you to some information that helps.